# How do you tell if a font is oblique?

Tags: c#, winforms

The built in font dialog looks like this [image]

and when I change it to oblique the appearance of my text does change. Yet there is no Oblique property on font. The Font.Style enum also doesn't contain Oblique. So somewhere in Font it knows to be oblique but that doesn't appear to be exposed publicly. How can I determine if a font is oblique?

What I am trying to do is check if two fonts are equal. I've tried font1.Equals(font2) but that always returns false.

Comment: Do you mean *Italic* ("Oblique")? `FontStyle.Italic`

Comment: I just assumed the lack of italic was some other problem I would have to deal with . To be fair I've been doing nothing but fixing things that shouldn't be problems for a while. But yeah, I meant italic. lol.

Comment: `Oblique` is actually a style, distinct from `Italic`. But, in .Net, the `FontStyle` is the same. You may notice that, sometimes, a Font doesn't actually have this style (there's no Font file that provides the *Italic* style), but if you select `FontStyle.Italic`, it will be rendered as *Italic*-ish anyway. It's rendered *oblique* (internal Font rendering feature, long story).

Answer (score 0):

You use `Style` property on font. And the style you are looking for is `System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic`

The easiest way to find this out is to go to designer file of your win forms app (or WPF), set the property in designer, like you showed, then go to code in the designer file and simply check it.

Here how it looks like (in Visual Basic, but it's analogic in C#):

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like this to me in my IDE. The background is white and forecolor is black. I tried to copy entire code and paste in texteditor, and have the same issue. How to fix? I used Paint to edit the screenshot of IDE screen, but colors still stay the same in the Visual Studio? need help, urgent!